# Joining Clause by Pronoun "Whose "

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns, clauses

Please consider the below sentence

> The only people whose interest will get hurt is/are businessmen.

is above sentence is correct? What kind of joining is that? I mean what is the grammatical term of such joining? Where online can I found such sentences to explore more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct with the verb "are" to agree with "people".

By "joining", I think you mean the relationship between "people" and "whose". 
 These are antecedent and relative pronoun. It can be said the the pronoun "whose" refers to the noun "people".

I suggest you use the search phrase "relative clauses with 'whose'" in a google search. You  will get very many results.